# ClassNotFoundException at Runtime in JasperReport 5.6.0

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to compile a sample report using JaspeReport 5.6.0. in NetBeans 8.0.
Using the following class code :

```
        package kinema.utility;

import java.util.HashMap;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;


public class ChiamaReport {

 public ChiamaReport() {


    try {


       JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("c:\report1.jrxml");
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap(), new JREmptyDataSource());
        JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint);
        jasperViewer.setVisible(true);
    } catch (JRException ex) {
    }

}
```

}

At Runtime, even if the application is compiled error free, when I try to compile the sample report, I have the error listed here  :

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1762)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1364)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$324(ContextMenuContent.java:1317)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer$$Lambda$150/319174947.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/96639997.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1757)
... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.<clinit>(JRLoader.java:81)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPropertiesUtil.loadProperties(JRPropertiesUtil.java:99)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.initProperties(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:94)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.<init>(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:71)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.<clinit>(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:59)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getDefaultInstance(JasperCompileManager.java:197)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:572)
at kinema.utility.ChiamaReport.<init>(ChiamaReport.java:30)
at kinema.BorderPaneController.callReport1(BorderPaneController.java:75)
... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 62 more
```

I don't understand what's wrong, can anybody help me to fix this?
thanks.

Comment: The answer is in your error message - it needs Apache commons-logging on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing [The Apache Commons Logging jar](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi) even when you don't require it, the `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader` needs it at Runtime. You can add the jar to your classpath and try to run your application agains.

You can find that (and other) library requirements in the [documentation](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-requirements).

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in this error for hours, and I've noticed that the full path for the jasper file was wrong, without the `.jasper` extension. I hope this can help you.